# Getting index counter on a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "id_1": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "id_2": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "foo": [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(["id_1", "id_2"])
```

which looks like this:

```
           foo
id_1 id_2
1    1     0.1
     1     0.1
     1     0.1
2    2     0.2
     2     0.2
     2     0.2
```

I want to have another column (`index`) that starts from `1` and goes up to the length of the `index` group, `3`. The output should look like this:

```
           foo index
id_1 id_2
1    1     0.1 1
     1     0.1 2
     1     0.1 3
2    2     0.2 1
     2     0.2 2
     2     0.2 3
```

How do I go about this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach could be as follows:

- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `level=0`, and apply [`Groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get consecutive numbers for each item in each group.
- Since the numbering will start at `0`, we use [`Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) to add `1` to the result.

```
df['index'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1)

df

           foo  index
id_1 id_2            
1    1     0.1      1
     1     0.1      2
     1     0.1      3
2    2     0.2      1
     2     0.2      2
     2     0.2      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` the `id_1` index whose level is 1 then `transform` on `foo` column to get length

```py
df['index'] = (df.groupby(level=1)['foo']
               .transform(lambda col: range(1, len(col)+1)))
```

```
print(df)

           foo  index
id_1 id_2
1    1     0.1      1
     1     0.1      2
     1     0.1      3
2    2     0.2      1
     2     0.2      2
     2     0.2      3
```